# Accessing memory past the class

Tags: c++, memory, alignment, padding

I have a peculiar problem. I want to create classes with variable length arrays in them. I don't want to allocate the arrays on the heap for the reasons of locality (the code slows down by a factor of 2 when I do). I don't want to use a virtual function because I don't want to pay for a function call. The following code works (on my compiler/platform), but with a caveat.

```
include <iostream>
include <boost/array.hpp>

struct Base
{
    Base(size_t s):
       size(s)                 {}
    int&        up(size_t i)   { return *(reinterpret_cast<int*>((&size) + 1) + i); }
    size_t      size;
};

template<size_t sz>
struct Derived: public Base
{
    boost::array<int, sz>       data;
    Derived(): Base(sz)         {}
};

int main()
{
    Derived<5> d5;
    d5.data[2] = 1234;
    Base* b = &d5;
    std::cout << b->up(2) << std::endl;
}
```

This is incredibly ugly; the reinterpret_cast<...> is a red flag. Moreover, the caveat is that this fails if I change `size_t` to, say, `short unsigned` (I guess the compiler pads the class).

So the question is: is there a way to make this portable? Is there a way to determine from `Base` where the first member variable will sit in its derived class?

Comment: Did you *measure* the cost of the virtual function call?

Comment: This is always going to be ugly.

Comment: Why does `Base` have to have a "unknown" size when `Derived` has a fixed size?  It doesn't look like you need a VLA.

Comment: @Matteo No, I haven't. I concede that it might not be expensive (and I'll double-check). For now consider it as a purely academic exercise.

Comment: @MooingDuck I need to determine the limit of the array at compile time.

Comment: What's the compiler?  Most compilers have a non-standard function to do VLAs.  `alloca` or some variant

Comment: @foxcub that exactly means that you can have a fixed size array.

Comment: I don't quite see why this is a) so complicated and b) which aspect of your code is "dynamic". It seems like the buffer size is a template parameter, i.e. a compile-time constant. If that's all you want, this could be a lot easier... I must be missing something, but I'd appreciate if you could explain a bit better.

Comment: @TamásSzelei Sorry I misspoke. I meant run-time.

Comment: @KerrekSB I want to flip a coin at run-time, and decide on the array size. The array size can be up to 16 (i.e. max size is fixed), so I can do a factory function with a switch statement. I want a pointer to a single class to access any one of the Derived<...> classes. Does that make sense?

Comment: @foxcub: Yes, see my answer -- I hope that's something in that direction.

Comment: You are on the right path. I solved this problem many times by using custom memory allocator. Works like a charm, giving the perfect data locality.

Comment: @VladLazarenko How would you do this with a custom memory allocator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an idea that came to my mind: let the `Derived` constructor store a pointer to its data inside a `Base` member.

```
struct Base
{
protected:
    size_t size;
    int * array;
    Base(size_t s, int * arr):
      size(s), array(arr)
    { }

public:
    int&   up(size_t i)   { return array[i]; }
    size_t getSize() { return size; }
};

template<size_t sz>
struct Derived: public Base
{
    std::array<int, sz> data;

    Derived():
      Base(sz, &data[0])
    { }
};

int main()
{
    Derived<5> d5;
    d5.data[2] = 1234;
    Base* b = &d5;
    std::cout << b->up(2) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Will this still work if I replace int as the contents of the array by short?

Comment: Oh, I misread what you are doing. Ignore my previous comment.

Comment: Excellent solution! Simple and portable. I accept (but the system says I have to wait 3 minutes).

Answer (score 2):

From your comment, it sounds like something like this might suffice:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
struct ArrayBase
{
  typedef T type;

  type & operator[](std::size_t i) { return buf[i]; }
  type const & operator[](std::size_t i) const { return buf[i]; }

protected:
  ArrayBase(type * p) : buf(p) { }

private:
  type * buf;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Array : ArrayBase<T>
{
  Array()
  : ArrayBase<T>(a.data())
  {
  }

  Array(Array const & rhs)
  : ArrayBase<T>(a.data())
  {
      std::copy(rhs.a.begin(), rhs.a.end(), a.begin());
  }

private:

  std::array<T, N> a;
};
```

Usage:

```
Array<int, 5> a5;
ArrayBase<int> & b = a5;
b[2] = 11;
Array<int, 5> a52 = a5;
a52[2] = 13;
```

Comment: ... which is basically what my answer does. :)

Comment: Right, this is basically Matteo's answer above. It indeed works. I'm still curious if it's possible to do it without the extra pointer, but that's pure curiosity.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: That's true. I hadn't looked through your answer while thinking about the OP's problem; sorry.

Comment: @foxcub: No, not portably. The base accessor function can only refer to something that it knows.

Comment: Well, it knows the sizeof(Base). Is there no requirement in the standard on padding in the derived classes?

Comment: @foxcub: No, padding is never controlled in any form or shape. Don't. OK, to give some meaning to this lifeless husk of an answer I made my version templated and gave it a proper copy constructor; now at least it isn't entirely useless.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dangerous, but fast and small answer:

```
template<class T>
struct alloca_magic {
    T* b;
    int s;
    alloca_magic(void* bu, int sz) 
       : b((T*)(bu)),s(sz) 
    {new(b)T[s];}
    ~alloca_magic() 
    {for(int i=0;i<s;++i)(b+i)->~T();}
    operator T*() {return b;}
};
#define alloca_magic(Type,Name,Size) void* t = alloca(sizeof(Type)*Size); alloca_magic<Type> Name(t,Size);

#include <iostream>     
struct test {
    int data;
    test() {std::cout << "ctor\n";}
    ~test() {std::cout << "dtor\n";}
};

void foo(int len) {
   std::cout << "begin foo\n";
   alloca_magic(test ,buffer,len);
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
       buffer[i].data = i;
   std::cout << "end foo\n";
}

int main() {
    int len; 
    std::cin >> len;
    std::cout << "begin main\n";
    alloca_magic(test ,buffer,len);
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        buffer[i].data = i;
    foo(len);
    std::cout << "end main\n";
}
```

http://ideone.com/ccvTR results:

```
begin main
ctor
ctor
ctor
begin foo
ctor
ctor
ctor
end foo
dtor
dtor
dtor
end main
dtor
dtor
dtor
```

For windows you'll have to replace `alloca` with `_alloca`.  Keep in mind that this is easily abused and broken, and if done with large numbers can cause a stack overflow.  I do *not* recommend this for anything besides speed tests, and probably not then either.

Comment: I actually need to use custom allocators, so alloca won't work for me.

Comment: custom allocators?  On the stack?

Comment: I don't want these objects on the stack. I want the array to be physically close to the rest of Base (or whatever it sits inside). I'm after locality, not the stack.

Comment: @foxcub: so you just want `std::array<obj, size>`?

Comment: No, the size is given at run-time. The two solutions above achieve what I want.